# android manifest merger cannot merge three manifest files

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest

i have 2 versions of AndroidManifest.xml files in my project, one is the main and another for debug.
in both of them i have android:label and in the debug version i have tools:replace="label"

after adding a library through gradle i suddenly see:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processMobileDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@label value=(XXXX Debug) from AndroidManifest.xml:36:13-45
>       is also present at [library_name] AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-41 value=(@string/app_name).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-20:19 to override.

it already exists there! what am i doing wrong?

**Edit1:**
main xml:

```
<application
            android:name="[package_name]"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

debug xml:

```
<application
            tools:replace="name, label"
            android:name="[package_name]"
            android:label="[debug_name]">
```

third party library xml:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: Can you post the manifest file please?

Comment: sure, i added the relevant application definitions from the manifest.xml files.
I tried replacing the label with android:label which are same thing but didt work either

Comment: Just put this tools:replace="android:label"'

Comment: it already exists in the debug xml but doesnt work

Comment: You have to do it where the Android studio says

Comment: it is already there and it doesnt help switching label with android:label. same effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I found out that the label should have the same value like all others.
  Meaning that `tools:replace` works only if all labels looks like this:
- `android:label="@string/app_name"`
- In my case it didn't work because in the debug manifest it looked like this:
- `android:label="debug name"`
- But once i changed it to `android:label="@string/app_name"` and added string in the `debug/values dir` it started working correctly.
  Seems like a bug in Android Studio.